# The difference between "proxy of" vs "proxy for" "proxy by"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between  "proxy for" and "proxy by"?
Is it correct to say "proxy of"?

For example:

```
proxy for english language learners.
proxy by english language learners.
proxy of english language learners.
```

What is the difference in meaning between these three sentences? Are they correct in regard to prepositions  usage?

Comment: Can you please update your question to provide us some context so that we can better assist you?

Comment: These sentences don't seem to make sense. Which meaning of proxy did you have in mind? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy for is the most common usage and means what you would expect. Proxy of is a different meaning and less clear, and proxy by is more ambiguous and probably should be avoided, though if the verb *to proxy* is used, then it is more sensible.

Two illustrative contexts:
An Nginx web proxy in front of a web service

1. The Nginx server is a proxy **for** the web service - I.e. it takes the place of the web service for clients
2. The web service has a proxy **of** an Nginx server - I.e. the proxy consists of an Nginx server
3. The web service is proxied **by** the Nginx server

A shareholder vote at a company meeting

1. The Broker is a proxy **for** the actual shareholder - I.e represents and votes for the shareholder at the meeting
2. The shareholder has a proxy **of** a broker present at the meeting
3. The absent shareholder is proxied **by** the broker at the meeting.

In short, use *for* with the noun proxy, and *by* with the verb proxy.